# Print only specific headers using Curb gem

Tags: ruby, curl, curb

I have a question about Ruby gem - Curb. I'm playing around with this gem and have this piece of code:

```
require 'curb'
require 'colorize'

def err(msg)
  puts
  puts msg.red
  puts 'HOWTO: '.white + './script.rb <domain>'.red
  puts
end

target = ARGV[0] || err("You forgot something....")

Curl::Easy.perform(target) do |curl| 
  curl.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; SunOS sun4u; en-US; rv:1.7.7) Gecko/20050421"
  curl.verbose = true
end
```

For example, when I try it on google.com, I get this headers (I don't put whole results from script):

```
Host: google.com
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; SunOS sun4u; en-US; rv:1.7.7) Gecko/20050421

* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x1c8dd80; (connection #0) 
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x1c8dd80; (connection #0) 
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x1c8dd80; (connection #0) 
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Location: https://www.google.cz/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=2stTVO2eJumg8we6woGoCg
< Content-Length: 259
< Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 17:50:18 GMT
< Server: GFE/2.0
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.01
```

My question, Is there any way, how to print only a specific headers via Curb? For example, I'd like only this headers on output, like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: https://www.google.cz/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=2stTVO2eJumg8we6woGoCg
Server: GFE/2.0
```

And nothing anymore. Is there any how to to do it via this gem? Or if you have any ideas how to do it using some another gem, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most difficult thing to just parse it yourself.

That's exactly what "[Get response headers from Curb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345805/curb-get-response-headers/14353011#14353011)" proposes.

Comment: Don't use things like "this StackOverflow answer" for anchor text. Instead, use something reasonably descriptive so people know more about what they're clicking on. See "[Don't use "click here" as link text](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)" for more information. SO makes it really easy to do that. See the edit to your answer.